# Update plot by selecting another page from a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app which displays a scatter plot of the iris dataset. Under this plot there is a table which displays the data. I was wondering if it is possible to connect somehow the plot and possibly the sidebar menu with the table in order to display only the data that are displayed in this certain page.

```
#ui.r
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('contents')
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    selectedData()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `input$tableId_rows_current` which gives the indices of rows on the current page. For more info check out [DT documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html). Here's the updated code -

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  req(input$contents_rows_current)
  palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
            "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

  par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
  plot(selectedData()[input$contents_rows_current, ],
       col = clusters()$cluster,
       pch = 20, cex = 3)
  points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
})
```

Comment: greta I was not aware of this.tnx